# find max and min number from a for loop in C

Tags: c

I am trying to find max and min number from a for loop.My code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readInts(int maxNumInts, int nums[])
{
    int count = 0;
    while (count < maxNumInts && scanf("%d", &nums[count]) == 1) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int nums[6] = { -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    int n = readInts(6, nums);
    int max = nums[0];
    int min = nums[0];
    int x = nums[0];
    int y[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += 2) {
        x = nums[i + 1] - nums[i];
        y[i] = x;
        if (y[i] > max) {
            max = y[i];
        }
        if (y[i] < min) {
            min = y[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", min);
    printf("%d\n", max);
}
```

I entered 10 30 60 100 150 210 for testing and it returns 10 60. It is supposed to be 20 60. It looks like the min is always the lowest entry minus 0....where did I do wrong?

Comment: I am trying to calculate the difference for every pair of number entered:x = nums[i+1]-nums[i];

Comment: `int min = nums[0];` is `int min = 10;`.  `nums[i+1]-nums[i]` is never smaller than that.  Try `int min = INT_MAX` or `int min = nums[1]-nums[0]`

Comment: You should also use `n` or you will maybe use you strange `-1` init number. also `max` have the same problem `int max = nums[1] - nums[0];`

Comment: Think twice at this (the array length is 6, valid indexes go from 0 to 5): `for(...;i<6;...)` { `...nums[i+1]...`. Can you go over the limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to find the minimum and maximum difference between numbers in a given set of numbers. And you are initializing the `min` and `max` to the first element of the set of numbers `num`.

Since you are comparing the subsequent differences between numbers with `min` and `max`, this will not work under two conditions:
a) If the *minimum* difference between numbers is *more* than the first element of `nums`
b) If the *maximum* difference between numbers is *less* than the first element of `nums`

For this to work:

1. You have to initialize `min` to some highest possible integer like `INT_MAX`.
2. You have to initialize `max` to some lowest possible integer like `INT_MIN`.

So change the following two lines:

```
int max = nums[0];
int min = nums[0];
```

to

```
int max = INT_MIN;
int min = INT_MAX;
```

And of course, you have to include the line `#include <limits.h>` at the beginning of the file for the values of `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`

Comment: Another option would be to initialize the min and max values with `nums[0] - nums[1]` (or the absolute value of that difference?) and then step through the other differences, taking care not to go outside the bounds of the array.  But your basic diagnosis — one calculation to initialize; different calculation to continue — is entirely valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see things in a different way. If you are searching for minimum and maximum *difference* between two consecutive elements of an array, then you can invent a "virtual" array - this array contains the differences:

```
10  30  60  100  150  210    <- nums[N]: real/original array
  20  30  40   50   60       <- diffs[]: virtual array
```

This virtual array has N-1 elements; every element is calculated on the fly with the formula `nums[i+1]-nums[i]`.

So, initially set variables *min* and *max* equal to the first element of virtual array; then scan subsequent elements (from 1 to N-1 of the *virtual* array, hence from 1 to N-2 of the *real* array), and compare them.

You could use a function to get elements from the virtual array, but in this case it would be too bloated.